# Run app from file_path variable PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to run some app, which path is in path_variable.

```
$a = 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat'
```

If I run with full path It work normally

```
& 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat'
```

But if I try do It with variable

```
& $a
```

It says

- CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with PowerShell 5. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Problem was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run code without space

```
&$a
```